# How can I arrange MDI children so they are entirely contained within the parent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I need to order windows in "rectangle" form. It's mean that when I have six windows it orders it in rectangle 2x3, when I have 5 windows it orders it 2x3 but without last window, when I have 9 windows it orders in 3x3. But I've got some troubles with coordinates  - child windows are out of bounds of mdiparent window.(img)

I used the same algorithm as I used in my mdi application on java

```
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<b;j++)
         try{
             indfr.get(counter).setLocation(i*theDesktop.getWidth()/a,j*theDesktop.getHeight()/b);
             indfr.get(counter).setSize(theDesktop.getWidth()/a,theDesktop.getHeight()/b);
             counter++;
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException exc){ break;}
```

where `indfr - arralist of JInternalFrames`,and `theDesktop - JDesktopPane`

Algorithm in c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
            try
            {
                list[counter].SetDesktopLocation(i*list[counter].MdiParent.Width/a, j*list[counter].MdiParent.Height/b);
                list[counter].Size = new Size(list[counter].MdiParent.Width/a, list[counter].MdiParent.Height/b);
                counter++;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
```

where list - `Form[] list = this.MdiChildern;`

What is wrong with coordinates?
(P.S it is not whole algorithm but it is the main loop where windows are ordering)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lines are those inside of your `try` block:

```
list[counter].SetDesktopLocation(i*list[counter].MdiParent.Width/a, j*list[counter].MdiParent.Height/b);
list[counter].Size = new Size(list[counter].MdiParent.Width/a, list[counter].MdiParent.Height/b);
counter++;
```

You're checking `Form.Width` and `Form.Height`, which return the *total* size of the form on the screen, including all of the borders. You can only place child windows inside the *client area* of the parent form, so you need to query the [`ClientSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9278sfx2.aspx) instead. That is defined as the size of the form, minus the borders and title bar; in other words, the area of the form in which children can be placed.

Re-write your `try` block to this, instead:

```
list[counter].SetDesktopLocation(i*list[counter].MdiParent.ClientSize.Width/a, j*list[counter].MdiParent.ClientSize.Height/b);
list[counter].Size = new Size(list[counter].MdiParent.ClientSize.Width/a, list[counter].MdiParent.ClientSize.Height/b);
counter++;
```

And then get rid of that silly empty `catch` block. If all you're *doing* when an exception is thrown is `break`ing, then there's no point in catching the exception. It will bubble up to the next exception handler, all the way to the global one if necessary. Only catch exceptions that you know specifically how to handle. You shouldn't be getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, and if you do, that's a bug in your code—you want to know about it so that you can fix it. That means not swallowing the exception.

---

[image: Clippy, the Office Assistant, now on Stack Overflow!] But, if I may channel Clippy here, it looks like you're trying to **tile your MDI children**.

In that case, there's an easier method than writing a bunch of `for` loops and manually setting the size and position of your children. Instead, just call the [`Form.LayoutMdi` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.layoutmdi.aspx) on your parent MDI form, and specify one of the [`MdiLayout` enumeration values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mdilayout.aspx). In this case, you probably want either `MdiLayout.TileHorizontal` or `MdiLayout.TileVertical`.

WinForms will take care of arranging your child windows precisely how you want them automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You specify you want to layout 2x3 for 5 forms 'without the last window', which I assume means you want an empty space where the last form would normally appear? If that's the case, this won't help you, but if that's not really important to you, you could just use the Form.LayoutMDI method which is a standard part of .NET Windows Forms:

```
LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileVertical);
```

The difference is that it won't leave empty space in the above scenario - 2 of the windows will appear larger in order to make use of the empty space. Try it anyway, and see if it'll do you.